# Why material-ui install / update return an error?

Tags: material-ui

i was updating the core library to latest version but npm return an error

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: @material-ui/core@latest
```

anyone have the same issue?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i removed the .npmrc file from my home dir and it works